# In Golang if I am calling a func inside fmt.Println(someName) without () then also there is no error but it is printing some hashcode. Why so?

Tags: go, goland

This may be a silly Question but I am new to Golang. so was trying with some code changes just to understand.
I created a func as shown below:

```
   func main() {
        fmt.Println(foo)
    }
    func foo() int {
        return 10
    }
```

In fmt.Println(foo) while calling foo, I am not giving () (normally we call func like foo()).
But it is not giving any error/exception, in return it is printing some hashcode like 0x10458bda0
and for every call it is getting changed. so just want to know why it is printing hash? In go are functions also temporarily stored in some memory and returning that address.

Comment: You are __not__ calling `foo`. You're passing the function to `Println`.

Comment: The program prints the underlying code pointer for the function `foo`.

Comment: "In go are functions also temporarily stored in some memory and returning that address." - not temporarily. You application is loaded from a file into memory when you execute it, and at that point your function has an address in memory. Note that it's not getting changed for every call - if you do `fmt.Println(foo)` multiple types, it prints the same output. It even prints the same output if you run the binary multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Golang stores the functions somewhere in the memory and passing a function to `fmt.Println()`, e.g., `fmt.Println(foo)` will print the address of that function in memory. That address does not change for every call to `fmt.Println(foo)`. On the other hand, if you passed a function call to the `fmt.Println()`, e.g., `fmt.Println(foo())`, the function `foo()` will be executed first and its return value will be printed.